# Fire showing in viewport, not in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

I have a great looking fire that shows up well in the viewport; however rendering results in just the smoke being rendered. I have absolutely no idea why.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Screenshots, sorry they are faded, I have already cached the sim. XD

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you attach an image of the Node editor for the fire and smoke material?

Comment: @Georges sure!! sorry for the lack of information :P i will include both the domain and the smoke object.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I'm using my phone, so I can't open the blend file, most probably it has to do with adding nodes for fire, unfortunately Cycles smoke material comes equipped with smoke material only, with a slot prepared to add a fire material!

Comment: @Georges edited. thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: Please attach an image of the materials node tree for the domain. The materials on the domain define how fire and smoke are rendered in cycles.

Comment: I meant the Node Editor, not the 3D view ;)

Comment: @cegaton it is default--while I edited many of the settings in the properties panel, I started out with a default "Quick Smoke" node tree and did not change anything there.

Comment: The link to the file is broken. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload and paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Joseph, change one of your panels to be a Node Editor, add that snap shot instead of one of the attached images

Comment: @Georges , cegaton my apologies, fixing.

Comment: Most probably you need to add few nodes to the material, unfortunately I'm away from my computer right now, fortunately, @cegaton is here ;)

Comment: @JosephFarah you're most welcome, I wish I could be more helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Slightly adjusted nodes to render fire:*

[image]

You need to add the bottom four nodes. They utilize the *Attribute* node's *flame* setting to detect fire. The *ColorRamp* node determines the color. The top *Multiply* node determines the smoke's thickness. The bottom *Multiply* node determines the fire's thickness.

*Result produced by these settings (a lightsaber on fire) (* :) *):*

[image]

This is your .blend file with the above nodes. I would include a screenshot of your final render instead of my stuff, but I do not have the smoke cache.

[image]

Comment: trying this now. Thanks very much for the answer!

Comment: @JosephFarah Glad to help!