# Fire shows up in default view but i can't get it to show up in render

Tags: rendering, particles, fire

[image]

[image]

I have tried putting in the multiplier as I've seen it in many answers as well as the color ramp but it still only shows up as grey particles in any rendering...?

Comment: Hi, maybe related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/fire-showing-in-viewport-not-in-render btw, image 1 is gone...

Comment: Please add the blend to help you further. Alternatively we need to see all the settings related to volumetrics.