# Smoke Simulation is different in 3D viewport from final render

Tags: smoke-simulation

when i render a smoke simulation,the rendered photo in 3D viewport is different from the rendered image when i press F12,in 3D viewport it's more dense and has orange colour but in the final render it's black and white and less dense[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the quick smoke feature creates the texture nodes for the smoke, it doesn't for the flames.  So when you render it, only the smoke is visible.

This has been covered before on Blender StackExchange:

[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/fire-showing-in-viewport-not-in-render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/fire-showing-in-viewport-not-in-render.)

This is also covered in Blender Guru's fire tutorial:

[Blender Guru - Fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply